# Add ReactJS Functional Component to Regular Web Application (JSX not getting parsed)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-enhancement

This [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) says Reactjs is progressive and can be added to a regular web app as follows:

Create a holder for the component:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Add React script tags to your header:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Load the React component:

```
<script src="mathjax.js"></script>
```

Create React Component (here is functional component in `mathjax.js`):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { MathComponent } from 'mathjax-react';

const e = React.createElement;

const math_styles = {
    "color" : "black",
    "display" : "none"
}

function MathJax() {
    
    const [count, setCount] = useState("");

    return e(`
        <div style={math_styles}>
            <MathComponent tex={String.raw`${count}`} />
        </div>
        `)
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);

export default MathJax;
```

Notice I added the wrap-around code as suggested in the link:

```
// at top
const e = React.createElement;

// at bottom
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
ReactDOM.render(e(MathJax), domContainer);
```

I also tried adding `type='module'` to the script tag:

```
<script type="module" src="mathjax.js"></script>
```

But I get the following **error**:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

It seems as though the JSX in the React component is causing issues. But the example code in the link above shows encasing the JSX inside a template literal string as I have done.

Technically, the example in the link shows the passing of additional arguments like this:

```
return e(
  'button',
  { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
  'Like'
);
```

But I'm not sure how I would make this work for a functional component like the one in my example.

Answer (score -1):

There is a huge difference between:

```
return e(
    'button',
    { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
    'Like'
);
```

and

```
return e(`
    <div style={math_styles}>
        <MathComponent tex={String.raw`${count}`} />
    </div>
`);
```

The syntax you're using is `JSX` and you're trying to include `JSX` in non-jsx aware environment/method which entirely defeats the purpose of the exercise. You should use either one or the other. `JSX` requires transpilation to normal javascript but avoids the pain of manually `React.createElement`-ing everything. The latter, on the other hand, runs everywhere as it is a valid javascript. There is no reason to combine the 2 approaches like that(and in most cases, it won't work at all). In your case it won't work for sure as you're not using any transpiler as `babel` to handle the job for you.

It's actually quite simple. Imagine that `React.createElement` just executes `document.createElement` under the hood(it's a bit more complicated, but it is a decent base for this particular case). In this context, what is expected from the engine when it encounters the following:

```
document.createElement(
    `<div style={math_styles}>
        <MathComponent tex={String.raw`${count}`} />
    </div>`
);
```

This is not a valid element. What element should the document create?!

`JSX` is syntactic sugar which is actually translated to the code you see in the first code sample.

So, when you transpile your `JSX`:

```
<div style={math_styles}>
    <MathComponent tex={String.raw`${count}`} />
</div>
```

it will be converted to:

```
React.createElement("div", {
    style: math_styles
}, React.createElement(MathComponent, {
    tex: String.raw`${count}`
}));
```

For the answer to be complete, your code is initially failing because you're closing the interpolated string prematurely by using a nested pair of ticks(`).